# Retrieving "when" a property was added to an ontology

Tags: jena, ontology, owl-api, apache-jena

I was wondering if it was possible to get the exact time stamp in a `dateTime` format for when a particular property, object or data, was added to the ontology.

For example if I have three owl individuals `A`, `B` and `C` and through my code in either OWL API or Apache Jena I add a property `relatedTo` to the ontology and create the assertions `A relatedTo B` and `A relatedTo C`, is there some function I can call on `A` to see that `A relatedTo B` was asserted at some `hh:mm:ss dd:mm:yyyy`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any API that I'm familiar with - by default, OWL does not record any such information. You could build a pattern to add a timestamp to each axiom (adding an axiom annotation to each axiom) but it would only be available for data you produce.

Some OWL storage systems might have that information internally, but I'm not aware of any of them exposing this for SPARQL interrogation.

Comment: That's too bad, I was hoping there would be some api for it. Oh well, thanks for your help!